# How do I access page parameters from a server route?

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit

I am creating a REST api using [sveltekit](https://kit.svelte.dev/) and have a [`+server.ts`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#server) file for accessing data by id.

The route is defined as: `<routes>/item/[itemId]/+server.ts`

How should I access the `itemId` from a server route?

### What I have tried

If this were a [`+page.svelte`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#page-page-svelte) file I would access it as follows:

```
import { page } from '$app/stores';

const { itemId } = $page.params;
```

However my understanding is that `$app/stores` not a server side concept (and indeed I am warned that `$page` does not exist).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is this.

```
// +server.ts

import { json, type RequestHandler } from "@sveltejs/kit";

export const GET: RequestHandler = ({ params }) => {
    console.log(params) // { itemId: '173' }

    return json(params)
}
```

You can access this endpoint from your client-side using fetch or if this data needs to be page data/params then you can convert it to a `+page.server.ts` or `+page.ts` or directly access them via `$page.params`

Comment: Oh that's perfect thank you!  I missed the parameter option.